# Matlab assignin('base',...) Resets

Tags: matlab, animation, workspace

I am attempting to write a function that, if called before any animation, will handle the close events without extra code in the animation file.

```
function matlabStopFunction(varargin)
persistent runs
if runs==2
    runs = [];
end
if isempty(runs)
    evalin('base','figure(''DeleteFcn'',@matlabStopFunction);');
    runs = 1;
else
    assignin('base','play',false);
    pause(1);
    runs = 2;
end
end
```

Here's a sample animation code that I've been using:

```
function sampleAnimation
matlabStopFunction;
r = 5;
th = 0;
play = true;
while play
    x = r * cosd(th);
    y = r * -sind(th);
    plot(x,y,'r*');
    axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
    th = th + 45;
    pause(0.25);
end
end
```

The stop function works fine creating the figure, and when I close the figure, it calls the same function as expected (including the assignin on line 10). However, when stepping through, when I first get back to the base function (sampleAnimation), play is false as would be expected: 
[image: Base Workspace]

But when I step one more line, play is reset to true

[image: Base Workspace]

Am I incorrectly assigning the value of play to false in the stop function, and if so, how could I correct this so that the animation stops when the figure is closed while keeping the code inside the animation to a minimum? I am trying to replicate the method on [this blog](https://zerocrossraptor.wordpress.com/matlab-undercover/creating-simple-animation-in-matlab/) except with all the code contained in a separate file.

I am running Matlab 2014b on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - you are modifying the value `play` in the base workspace - where as the loop is in the workspace of the sampleAnimation function -> so you are not changing the required value to stop the animation.  To verify this clear your variables in the base workspace `clear` before you run your code and you will see that the variable `play` is created and set to false.

By the way there is a much simpler way to do this, you animation can create a figure and then you can stop when it is deleted:

```
function sampleAnimation
  h = figure;
  r = 5;
  th = 0;
  while ishandle ( h )
    x = r * cosd(th);
    y = r * -sind(th);
    plot(x,y,'r*');
    axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
    th = th + 45;
    pause(0.25);
  end
end
```